# Different values in the invoice and in the mail in the order from prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a problem with the order in prestashop cms. The values in the invoice differ from the values ​​in the email - that confirms the order. The invoice all values ​​are correct. However, in the e-mail discount and VAT are incorrect.

[image]

What is the problem? How can I correct values ​​in the mail? 
Which files are responsible for displaying the values ​​in the mail ( eg {total_price} )

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a sort of "conflict" in your tax configuration.
It seems your invoice tax configuration is set to show products and vouchers with tax excluded, while your frontend displays them with tax included.

To check what your tax settings are enter **tax** (or **taxe** in your case) in the search box in your backoffice. Then look for the **Tax** category and check what your options are, make sure they are consistent throughout your backoffice.

To answer your last question, class `PayementModule` is responsible for the content of the confirmation email.